# Why is this converted to an array using .apply() with jQuery.when and jQuery.Deferred.resolveWith?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apply, jquery-deferred, jquery-3

Using jQuery 3.0.0, given

```js
$(function() {

  var n = 5;

  function jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith(n) {
    
    var arr = $.map(Array(5), function(_, i) {
      return $.Deferred();
    });

    var obj = {
      "index": null
    };

    var promises = $.when.apply(null, arr.map(function(promise, i) {
      return i < n 
             ? promise.resolveWith(obj, [i]) 
             : promise.rejectWith((obj.index = i, obj)
               , [new Error(i + " is not less than " + n)])
    }));
    
    function success(...result) {
      console.log("resolved, result:", result, "this:", this);
    }
    
    function err(error) {
      console.log("rejected, error:", error, "this:", this);
    }
    
    return promises.then(success, err);
    
  }
  
  jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith(n)
  .then($.proxy(jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith, null, --n))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
</script>
```

the first call to `jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith` should return an array of resolved jQuery promise values at `.then()` chained to `promises`, where `this` is an array of `obj` objects.

The second call to `jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith` should return `Error`, with `this` set to single object `obj`.

The expected result of `success` is `this` set to single `obj`, as single object was passed to `deferred.resolveWith`.

Though the expected result is not returned, at `javascript` at stacksnippets, the single object can be returned by using `.bind()` or `$.proxy()` at `.then()` chained to `promises`.

```js
$(function() {

  var n = 5;

  function jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith(n) {
    
    var arr = $.map(Array(5), function(_, i) {
      return $.Deferred();
    });

    var obj = {
      "index": null
    };

    var promises = $.when.apply(null, arr.map(function(promise, i) {
      return i < n 
             ? promise.resolveWith(obj, [i]) 
             : promise.rejectWith((obj.index = i, obj)
               , [new Error(i + " is not less than " + n)])
    }));
    
    function success(...result) {
      console.log("resolved, result:", result, "this:", this);
    }
    
    function err(error) {
      console.log("rejected, error:", error, "this:", this);
    }
    
    return promises.then($.proxy(success, obj), err);
    
  }
  
  jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith(n)
  .then($.proxy(jQueryWhenApplyResolveRejectWith, null, --n))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
</script>
```

Questions:

1. Why is `this` converted to an array from the plain object passed to
   `.resolveWith()`; while the same object passed to `.rejectWith()`
   returns a single object using `$.when.apply()` pattern?
2. Is the expected behaviour of using `$.when.apply()` or
   `.resolveWith()`, or both in same procedure, `this` being set to an
   array containing original `this` multiplied by the number of
   resolved jQuery promise objects?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the jQuery documentation doesn't state the effect on `this` when multiple promises are aggregated, having been given a context with `.resolveWith()`. Therefore, expectation is somewhat personal and hard to define. Personally, I can accept the behaviour exhibited. However, I do find the behaviour somewhat quirky when promises are aggregated, having been resolved with a mixture of `resolve()` and `resolveWith()` - `this` seems OK but the result delivered via `...result` certainly doesn't meet my expectation.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 _"but the result delivered via `...result` certainly doesn't meet my expectation"_ What is your expectation? There may have been a bug concerning this, or similar result with `.notifyWith()` at jQuery's github issues page. Will check. Did not expect `this` to be converted into an array, here.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The closest related issue could find so far https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1839

Comment: Sorry, I take that back, I was doing something stupid. Mixed `resolve()` and `resolveWith()` behaves OK.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 _" 
Sorry, I take that back"_ Take what back? _"resolveWith() behaves OK"_ Expected result is for `this` to be converted to an array having copies of original `this` multiplied by the amount of resolve jQuery promises?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Do you mean that each returned  has its own `this` context, and that an error handler has only a single context?

Comment: I find the behaviour of `jQuery.when().then()` [easier to understand after testing like this](https://jsfiddle.net/jkaes5fy/)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Used `{index:null}` to indicate which promise was rejected

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this converted to an array using .apply() with jQuery.when and
>   jQuery.Deferred.resolveWith?
>
> 1. Why is this converted to an array from the plain object passed to .resolveWith(); while the same object passed to .rejectWith() returns
>      a single object using $.when.apply() pattern?
> 2. Is the expected behaviour of using $.when.apply() or .resolveWith(), or both in same procedure, this being set to an array
>      containing original this multiplied by the number of resolved jQuery
>      promise objects?

Each promise object has its own context. The array returned as `this` at `success` function represents the `this` value of each resolved promise.  Since the context could be changed between the promise being resolved or rejected, the `this` is not flattened to a single object, or single value within the returned array, but distinct for each jQuery promise object originally passed to `$.when.apply()`.

Yes, believe this to be expected behaviour. Note that `$.when.apply()` is not a jQuery method, but a way to pass an array of promises to `$.when()` and retrieve array of resolved promises at `.then()`, or single rejected promise if any one of the promises in passed array is rejected.

If expected result is single `this` at `success` where an array of resolved promises is return value, you can use `.bind()` or `$.proxy()` to set `this` at `success` function.

```
  return i < n 
         ? promise.resolve(i) // use `.resolve()` instead of `.resolveWith()` here
         : promise.rejectWith((obj.index = i, obj)
           , [new Error(i + " is not less than " + n)])
```

```
  return promises.then(success.bind(obj), err); // use `.bind()` to set `this`
```

There is no need to adjust `err` function as only single rejected promise is returned to `onRejected` handler, where `this` would be single value, not an array.